# How to Import data from .sql.bz2 file to hdfs?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am new to Hadoop and hdfs and I have a compressed SQL file :

**ETIMCBG11-Jul-2016-08-00.sql.bz2**

I do not have access to the database from where this file was Exported.

and i need to import this data into hdfs file system for Hadoop.

Is there any way to do this directly without having to import the file back to another MySQL Database and then connect using [Sqoop](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/sqoop/1.4.6) ?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, this can't be done.

Sqoop makes JDBC connection with RDBMS and perform range queries (*depending upon number of mappers*).

Sqoop can't read from sql dump.